# With regard to COVID-19 what happens to droplets after coughing or sneezing?

Tags: covid-19, coronavirus, airborne-transmission

Let's say 15 minutes after a person coughs or sneezes, where does the droplet go? Up in the air and down to the ground? Is it different inside a building?

Comment: Are you referring to `Covid-19`?

Comment: @America Yes, that's what I'm referring, too

Comment: we have a tag ;) you could add `coronavirus` tag too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data suggests droplets remain in the air up to 3 hours, and longer for droplet nuclei.  Where they go depends on the local temperatures, humidity and air flows.

[image]

The image shows a cough on the left and a sneeze on the right.

> Currently, the term droplet is often taken to refer to droplets >5 μm in diameter that fall rapidly to the ground under gravity, and therefore are transmitted only over a limited distance (e.g. ≤1 m). In contrast, the term droplet nuclei refers to droplets ≤5 μm in diameter that can remain suspended in air for significant periods of time, allowing them to be transmitted over distances >1 m (Stetzenbach, Buttner & Cruz, 2004; Wong & Leung, 2004). Other studies suggest slightly different definitions, with ranges for “large” droplets, “small” droplets and droplet nuclei being >60 μm in diameter, ≤60 μm in diameter and <10 μm in diameter, respectively (Tang et al., 2006; Xie et al., 2007). The concept is that the naturally and artificially produced aerosols will contain a range of droplet sizes, whose motion will depend significantly on various environmental factors, such as gravity, the direction and strength of local airflows, temperature and relative humidity (which will affect both the size and mass of the droplet due to evaporation).

Oops, breathing and talking can produce droplets yet health authorities continue to claim that masks are not needed (to stop wearers from broadcasting droplets into the environment)

> Humans can produce respiratory aerosols (droplets) by several means, including breathing, talking, coughing (Figure C.1, A), sneezing (Figure C.1, B) and even singing (Wong, 2003; Toth et al., 2004).

We are being told that the main droplets are the larger ones being emitted but talking for 5 mins can produce droplet nuclei the same as a cough

> Published data have suggested that sneezing may produce as many as 40 000 droplets between 0.5–12 μm in diameter (Cole & Cook, 1998; Tang et al., 2006) that may be expelled at speeds up to 100 m/s (Wells, 1955; Cole & Cook, 1998), whereas coughing may produce up to 3000 droplet nuclei, about the same number as talking for five minutes (Cole & Cook, 1998; Fitzgerald & Haas, 2005; Tang et al., 2006). Despite the variety in size, large droplets comprise most of the total volume of expelled respiratory droplets. Further data on the behaviour of droplet dispersion in naturally generated aerosols are needed.

Small droplets fall to the ground where they dry up before they reach the ground but some become droplet nuclei on their way down which allows them to remain airborne

> In the classic study of airborne transmission, Wells (1934) was able to identify the difference between disease transmission via large droplets and by airborne routes. Wells found that, under normal air conditions, droplets smaller than 100 μm in diameter would completely dry out before falling approximately 2 m to the ground. This finding allowed the establishment of the theory of droplets and droplet nuclei transmission depending on the size of the infected droplet. The Wells evaporation-falling curve of droplets (see Figure C.2) is important in understanding airborne transmission and transmission by large droplets. Wells' study also demonstrated that droplets could transform into droplet nuclei by evaporation.

And what happens to droplet nuclei

> Droplet nuclei floating on the air may be carried by the movement of air. Entrainment of air into neighbouring airspaces may occur during the most innocuous daily activities; for example, as a result of people walking, or the opening of a door between a room and the adjacent corridor or space (Hayden et al., 1998; Edge, Paterson & Settles, 2005; Tang et al., 2005, 2006). In addition, the air temperature (and therefore air density) differences across an open doorway will also cause air exchange to occur between the two areas, providing a second mechanism to allow air into other areas (Tang et al., 2005, 2006) (see Figure C.3).

which is why they use negative pressure rooms when doing a procedure that can form aerosols

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK143281/

Comment: Excellent answer especially explanation how enough talking is equivalent to a cough. When coughing into the sleeve though I assume it absorbs most droplets.

Comment: Well, talking lacks the same energy added to the droplets so i would think not more dangerous but maintain that 2 m separation distance.

Comment: Sorry I had revised my comment making your reply somewhat confusing to others.

Comment: It stays in aerosol form for 3 hours and with modern air tight buildings it probably doesn't matter. Interestingly I have hearsay testimony a local firefighters have noticed lots of swollen eyes taking people to hospital lately. I'm wondering if eyeballs can encounter these droplets too and they are not only just breathed in.

Comment: I think that's wrong.  It can be droplets for 3 hours but aerosol much longer.  yes, the red eyes are conjunctivitis from virus infecting the eyes which is why everyone is wearing eye protection.

Comment: Not everyone. At work we were ordered to wear N95 masks and gloves but not air tight googles in low risk environment where we encounter 20 strangers a day. Meanwhile at Safeway no masks, no gloves and definitely no googles by staff who encounter thousands of strangers each day. I'm not trying to be alarmist I just think it's a waste to wear N95 mask when logic dictates low risk. At work I only wear eye protection when using the angle grinder a few times a year. Plus N95 masks appear to be a coveted item.

Comment: Many countries are trying to avoid the full PPE used by China - who knows why?  The principal of least harm should be followed here - full PPE.

Comment: You were a leader as CDC now says talking can spread droplets: [COVID-19 Can be Transmitted Through Talking, Research Finds](https://sports.yahoo.com/covid-19-transmitted-talking-research-023143092.html?src=rss). Also home made masks were ordered by Pentagon for soldiers. There is a news story today of red eye infection being symptom of Novel Coronavirus Infection: [Pink eye may be an overlooked symptom of COVID-19](https://www.ctvnews.ca/health/coronavirus/pink-eye-may-be-an-overlooked-symptom-of-covid-19-1.4884513) You were ahead of the curve on this pandemic. Too bad MSM and SE missed out.

Comment: Also I notice on the bus a guy yawning and mimicking that action later I wondered if 5 minutes of talking is equivalent to a cough if a yawn might be equal to 20% of a cough, or whatever. In essence if it would be prudent to yawn into your elbow in public.

Comment: Yawning, just tried, is breathing in.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm right about yawning but I correlate the strong inhale with a strong exhale. I strongly disagree on Kiwi PM. I think she has done an outstanding job on keeping Sars-Cov 2.0 out of the country. No wonder Shania Twain emigrated to your country from Timmins Ontario with her "placid" husband. Given the weather forecast here and USA to the south with constant problems to solve, I envy you.

Comment: Taiwan did an outstanding job.  NZ had the prior experience to follow of the Asian countries but still could have done a lot better.  Our opposition party were strongly advocating for border controls in January which were ignored.

Comment: Agreed about Taiwan but they have a natural discomfort with China and embrace US military so their decision making is skewed. Sorry I don't know your magesty's official opposition party but bear in mind it is their job to counter the party of government and they are just often wrong as they are right when viewed through 20-20 hindsight glasses. I take it you voted for the other "guy" then?

Comment: On a side note for a country of 5.1 million people you get a lot of spotlights with your Christ Church earthquake, 51 executed in Muslim Mosque, Shania Twain and  NovelCoronavirus success. it almost seems like too much news to be a no news country on my radar. Not forgetting the fact you exist too. After all the odds on meeting a physician who is a software developer?

Comment: Also Taiwan is about 80 miles away from China I think and Honk Kong being much closer did a better job. That said China did a better job against China by locking down Wuhan and then Hubei province. It will be interesting to see how good a job Japan will do going forward having been conquered by USA.